# Какой здесь знак препинания и нужен ли вообще?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужен ли на месте скобок знак препинания, какой и почему?
*«Мы всё время приходим в разное время, сейчас вот пришли за час, а в прошлом месяце () так вообще опоздали».*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Вашем предложении "так" — частица, не требующая знаков. Ср. примеры из правила:

*А вот я **так** всегда в двенадцать ложусь.*

*Там **так** никто и не пришел, и ко мне не придут!*

---

**[ТАК, наречие, союз, частица, вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_707)**

1. Наречие. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

> *Значит, вы допускаете мысль, что она у вас могла быть, иначе вы бы не построили **так** фразу, значит... А. Битов, Дело о двух банках
>   тушенки. До того доходило, что иду, бывало, по улице и **так** с
>   головой влезу в эту «тайную борьбу», что мне, правда, казалось, что за
>   мной следят, и я оглядывался на перекрестках.* В. Шукшин, Мечты.

2. Союз. То же, что «в таком случае, следовательно» или «но, однако». Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «так», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.

> *Ну, у кого спросить? У Самуильсона? **Так** Самуильсон скажет, что он вас в глаза не видал.* Н. Тэффи, Свой человек. *…Всякий раз как
>   придется подписывать строгий приговор, **так** мурашки по телу
>   пробегут.* А. Герцен, Мимоездом. *К вину действительно припадошен,
>   **так** это опять же его дело.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Балабурда.

3. Частица. Обособляется в значениях «ничего особенного» и «да, действительно».

> *...Сошелся со мной один пропащий совсем человек. **Так**, в харчевне сошлись.* Ф. Достоевский, Честный вор. «Он хотел завести разговор?» –
>   *«**Так**, но я избежал этого».*

**В остальных случаях частица «так» не требует постановки знаков препинания.**

> *Я была ишо маленькая, годов семь **так**, восемь было.* В. Шукшин, Сны матери. *Что ж? Лекцию **так** лекцию – мне решительно всё равно.*
>   А. Чехов, О вреде табака. *А вот я **так** всегда в двенадцать
>   ложусь.* А. Чехов, Гость. *Там **так** никто и не пришел, и ко мне не
>   придут!* В. Высоцкий, Опять дельфины.

4. Вводное слово (в начале предложения или части сложного предложения). То же, что «например». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в [Прил. 2](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).

> *Мой клиент – мужчина пятидесяти двух лет... Несмотря на такой возраст, он еще имеет людей, которые дают ему взаймы. **Так**, у него
>   два портных, шьющих на него в кредит.* А. Чехов, Брак через 10–15 лет.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужен. Если без "так", то очевидно, что не нужен? А что меняет частица "так"?